# How to implement change detection so the given example works

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

In this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-od9vzu) change detection has not been implemented and the Flip button does not work. I would appreciate hints on how to go about implementing it. The model is the class that needs to drive appearance of the application.

Comment: Change detection is not turned off. The problem is that your directive handles the changes only in life cycle event **ngAfterViewInit**. Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n6lbnt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. I am beginning to understand how the change detection reasons :). The *ngIf directive forces it to check the 'show' property of the component and that now changes after every flip. One thing that I do not understand is what you have written above about ngAfterViewInit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used *ngIf to remove that div element from the DOM.

```
<div *ngIf="show">
```

See more details about ngIf [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

The interesting point here is that ngIf will not just hide the DOM node it will destroy it (remove it from the DOM). Once the condition is truthy new instance will be created.

Once that is done. I added it back that way the directive will be added again to the newly created elements. And it's life cycle hook ngAfterViewInit will be triggered. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`SomeComponent[${this.randomNumber}]::ngOnInit`);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(`SomeComponent[${this.randomNumber}]::ngAfterViewInit`);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log(`SomeComponent[${this.randomNumber}]::ngOnDestroy`);
    console.log('');
  }
```

Here is a simple [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqvwea) to see these hooks in action.